# Matlab syntax when importing an image from folder

Tags: matlab, syntax

I don't quite understand what line 5 of the following code is doing.
First 4 lines are importing the image from the folder and then storing it in "image1". Then on line 5 i dont get what is being done.

```
numFolder=fullfile('NumberZero/','Zero/');
for i=1:10;
    numName=sprintf('%d.bmp',i);
    image1=imread([numFolder, numName]);
    im1(:,:,i)=image1; % what is this line doing?
end
```

Comment: It is storing the image into a 3D array where the dimensions are [rows columns nImages]

Comment: @Suever Now I understand. Thank you. You can post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Added. Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loop is simply loading all of the image data into a variable called `im1`. The dimensions of this variable are going to be `[nRows, nColumns, nImages]`. This assumes that the images coming in are actually grayscale rather than RGB (third dimension == 1)

Once this is loaded in, you can then access the different images via the folling approach.

```
first_image = im1(:,:,1);
second_image = im1(:,:,2);
```

As a side note, it is recommended [to *not* use `i` as a loop index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on the "MATLAB Central" Q&A and "Image Analyst" answered my question very nicely.

The line

```
im1(:,:,i)=image1;
```

takes a 2D image called image1 and sticks it into the i'th slice (plane) of a 3D image called im1. If im1 already has i slices, then it just overwrites the i'th slice. If im1 does not yet have i slices, then this code will append a slice to grow the 3D image in the "Z" direction. So it's turning 2D images stored on your disk into a 3D image. The images1's must be grayscale for this code to work.

Comment: Just curious, what caused this to be better than my answer below?

Comment: @Suever sorry its just that for me this explanation was more understandable. But i will mark yours as if you need it :P

Comment: It's not a problem at all. I'm just always trying to learn what makes one answer better than another!